# Javascript how to search double byte string with single byte string and vice versa

Tags: javascript, search, multibyte

I have a string

```
var str = "か22222";
```

i want to search like this

str.indexOf("か２"); where "か２" both are multi byte characters and "str" has only "か" as multibyte

but still I should get the result of indexOf as 0.

is there any way of doing this is JS ??

Comment: All strings in JavaScript are Unicode (with some fun dealing with surrogate pairs; I believe the internal mechanism is UTF-16 - [see here](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-encoding)).

Answer (score 1):

No. The character `2` (U+32, DIGIT TWO) and the character `２` (U+FF12, FULLWIDTH DIGIT TWO) are, for whatever awful historical reason, two completely different things -- searching for one will not match the other.

Comment: +1 Good catch. I completely failed to recognize different glyphs D':

Comment: In many fonts, they look absolutely identical. I blame Japan.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the simplest thing would be to do would be

```
var result=str.match(/か[２2]/);
alert("match at "+result.index);
```

You could also use something like [１-９] as a character range, since the full-width digits occupy contiguous codepoints.

A more general solution would be to do a conversion between "multi-byte" (better known as "full width") and the single width characters at some point. The slightly hacky conversion is to add 0xfee0 to the corresponding half-width code point. Let's assume you are going to transform the input string to full-width forms; you could do it like this:

```
var arr=[];
for(var i;i<str.length;i++){
  arr[i] = str.charPointAt(i);
  i(arr[i]>=0x30 && arr[i]<=0x39) { arr[i] += 0xfee0; }
}
var full_width_string=String.fromCharCode.apply(null,arr);
```

Now you can search against full-width string.

Better to use a Unicode library or normalizer for Javascript.